# my python calculator gives an invalid syntax error

Tags: python

I can't get my calculator to work. when I run it, it says that y elif statement is invallid, functions are above this clode block, it should work.

```
choice = raw_input("chose an operator [1,2,3,4]")
num1 = raw_input("input number 1")
num2 = raw_input("input number 2")

if choice == 1:
    print(num1,"+",num2,"=",add(num1,num2)

elif choice == 2:
    print(num1,"-",num2,"=",minus(num1,num2)

elif choice == 3:
    print(num1,"x",num2,"=",times(num1,num2)

elif choice == 4:
    print(num1,"/",num2,"=",divide(num1,num2)
else:
    print("that's not a valid operator")
```

and here is my error

```
  File "calculator.py", line 27
    elif choice == 2:
```

Comment: You missed a `)` after each `print` in `elif`. It should be, `print(num1,"+",num2,"=",add(num1,num2))`, not `print(num1,"+",num2,"=",add(num1,num2)`

Comment: You missed the last `)` in all your prints except the last one

Comment: also if your using python 2.x you need to put `" "` around each number in the if statements like: `if choice == "1"` because raw_input tells it is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing closing `)` in all your print statements except last one.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ) on each line

```
if choice == 1:
    print(num1,"+",num2,"=",add(num1,num2)   # <--- needs ) to close
```

Note: 
raw_input "asks" for a string value, in your case you should change

```
if choice == 1:
```

to

```
if choice == "1":
```

otherwise just use input

ex:

```
choice = input("chose an operator [1,2,3,4]:\n")  # <- added \n, puts a new line at that point
```